# Is there any equipment with Life Drain?

Tags: zenonia-3

Is it possible to find, or has anyone found equipment with Life Drain (aka **HP Consume**) attributes on it?

I know the Warrior class has a Level 40 skill which gives this, but I want to give my Assassin some sort of Life Drain to make Execution Room runs easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup I found a lvl90+ unique boots that give me +10% hp absorption